# Datalist Itemcommand event is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am trying to work on itemcommand event of datalist. I want to work with the button that is bind in datalist. But when i add a breakpoint on the itemcommand event the event doesnot run.Please tell me why it is not working here is the datalist source and my code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
            onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand1" >
        <ItemTemplate>
         <ul>
        <li>
    <a href="#"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("pictureurl") %>' Width="170px" Height="104px" /></a><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fullname") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Icons/accept1.png" CommandName="Accept"   />&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Icons/decline.png"   />&nbsp;

        </li>
        </ul>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Code:

```
  if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
        {
            string id = DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString() ;

            SqlCommand CmdAcceptRequest = new SqlCommand("Update FriendRequest set requeststatus='Accept' where RequestFrom='" + id + "'", con);
            CmdAcceptRequest.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            CmdAcceptRequest.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CmdAcceptRequest.Dispose();



         }
```

This code is not working for me. Item command event is not working Please experts tell me where i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are databinding the `DataList` on every postback. Check the [`IsPostNack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property, e.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         DataBindDataList();
    }
}

private void DataBindDataList()
{
    var dataSource = getSource(); // some data
    DataList1.DataSource = dataSource;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

Otherwise events won't be triggered if you `DataBind` a webdatabound control to it's `DataSource` again. This is true only for manually databound controls not for declarative datasource controls like `SqlDataSource` or `ObjectDataSource`.

Comment: actually i add a breakpoint also on itemcommand event but when i click on button in datalist breakpoint running

Comment: @AzadChouhan: But it is true that you are using a manual datasource? What means "no response from the itemcommand event" in your qustion and "but when i click on button in datalist breakpoint running" in your last comment?

Comment: I mean to say when i add a breakpoint on code breakpoint should have to work but it is not working.. and no response from the itemcommand event means itemcommand is not working